# How do I deal with this weird error function using dcast?

Tags: r, dcast

I am using dcast in order to widen my data table:

```
df <- dcast(setDT(dt),locus ~ Indiv,value.var = 'x')
```

I have a data table that is 1254840 observations and 3 variables, I need to make it 3270 observations and 373 variables.

But every time I try to use the above function this error pops up:

```
Error in forderx(x, cols, sort=true, retgrp = false) :
 Failed to alloc cradix_counts
```

I think it is a memory issue but I cant find a way to get it to work, I have used `gc()`, and `memory.limit()` to no avail.

Is there anything I can do to combat this error or is there another way to widen my data table?

Comment: Is there a way you can share a sample of data? Obviously you cannot add all of the data, but can you add the output from perhaps `dput(dt[1:30,c("locus","Indiv","x")]`, assuming that that provides consistent and sufficient representative variability to be able to expand it? I realize it may `dcast` just fine on your console with that size data (or maybe it doesn't?), but it might help us find alternative ways to get to the same result without a memory explosion.

Comment: hey, sorry I cant really share the data as it is genome sequences of individuals. hope you understand

Comment: First, put the `setDT` before the `dcast` call. We want to exclude the possibility of some weird bug related to `setDT`. Then provide any information you can about your data, e.g., data types, variability, etc. It would be best if you provided code creating simulated data that allows us to reproduce the error.

Comment: NavGarg, I completely understand proprietary/private data. However, that does not preclude you from giving us a representative sample. Give us something random. Use a public dataset (`mtcars`, `iris`, `diamonds`, `starwars`, ...). But give us something or the question is much harder to investigate much less answer authoritatively ... and therefore much less likely to get an answer at all.